# How can I split a string in zshell and capture a substring-to-end-of-line?

Tags: linux, zsh

I have a string I would like to split into a substring and return the second subset of the result as a string. How can I do this in zshell?

I can split at a keyword and return the next word of the substring like this:

```
line="quick brown fox jumps over sleepy dog"
splits=${(MS)line##over*}
nextword=$splits[(w)1] #<-- returns "sleepy"
```

How can I get the entire substring after the split such as *"sleepy dog"* or *"sleepy brown dog"* (if the string contains more words)? In essence, what I'm looking for in zshell is the `awk` equivalent of:

```
echo "quick brown fox jumps over sleepy dog" | awk -F'over' '{print $2};'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative range offset (`-1` in this case) at the end of your `splits` indexing. To get from `sleepy` all the way up to the last element, you could just use `$splits[(w)1,-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:

```
[[ $line =~ "over (.*)" ]]
next_word=$match[1]  # or just $match
```